# Mailing file as attachment through form

Tags: php, ajax, forms, email, phpmailer

So I am currently utilizing a HTML form to obtain information from customers (in a landing page context) that sends via email all the information that the user submitted, and it's working fine so far.

However, I've added a file upload field to the HTML form ($userfile) but I wasn't able to handle the file upload and attachment properly. I've been testing and tweaking around a lot, but I can never seem to get it working.

This is the PHP file that I'm currently utilizing, based on a pre-existing template.

```
$to             = "email@email.com"; 

$nome     = $_POST["nome"];
$email    = $_POST["email"];
$website  = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";

if (isset($email) && isset($nome)) {
    $subject  = "Lead: $nome";
    $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: ".$nome." <".$email.">\r\n"."Reply-To: ".$email."\r\n" ;
    $msg      = 'Hey Admin, <br/> <br/> Here are the details:';
    $msg     .= ' <br/> <br/> <table border="1" cellpadding="6" cellspacing="0" style="border: 1px solid  #eeeeee;">';
    foreach ($_POST as $label => $value) {
        $msg .= "<tr><td width='100'>". ucfirst($label) . "</td><td width='300'>" . $value . " </tr>";
    }
    $msg      .= " </table> <br> --- <br>Sent by $website";

    $mail =  mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers);

    if($mail) {
            echo 'success';
    } else {
            echo 'failed';
    }

} // END isset

?>
```

And also the AJAX POST

```
var dataString = $(form).serialize();

            /* 
             AJAX POST
             --------- */

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: dataString,
                url: "php/contact.php",
                cache: false,
                success: function(d) {
                    $(".form-group").removeClass("has-success");
                    if (d == 'success') {
                        if (noredirect) {
                            $('#js-contact-result').fadeIn('slow').html('<div class="alert alert-success top-space">' + success_msg + '</div>').delay(3000).fadeOut('slow');
                        } else {
                            window.location.href = redirect;
                        }
                    } else {
                        $('#js-contact-result').fadeIn('slow').html('<div class="alert alert-danger top-space">' + error_msg + '</div>').delay(3000).fadeOut('slow');
                    }
                    $("#js-contact-btn").attr("disabled", false);
                }
            });
```

If anyone could point me to some resources where I can learn more or actually help me solve it, I would really appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: This isn't PHPMailer. Are you trying to use PHPMailer?

Comment: @billy.farroll You're right, I edited the title out.

Answer (score 0):

```
var dataString = $(form).serialize();
```

does not allow for uploading files

instead use a formdata javascript object

```
var dataString = new FormData(form);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use form.serialize() for file input.

Check here: [jQuery Ajax File Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload)